# How does event handling work internally within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, internals, spidermonkey

Specifically [Spidermonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/).

I know you write functions and attach them to events to handle them.

Where is the `onClick` handler defined and how does the JS engine know to fire `onClick` events when the user clicks?

Any keywords, design patterns, links, etc are appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Aggregating links I find useful here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_events.cc

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/dom/src/events/nsJSEventListener.cpp

Comment: SpiderMonkey is open source, of course, you can always just...[browse](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/src/)...

Comment: @TJ, Spidermonkey is just a JS engine, the event-driven nature of the DOM is implemented on top of it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you expect to be able to use this knowledge? In other words, is there something that you'd like to do such that the answer to this mystery would guide your approach for a solution?

Comment: @Pointy, I would like to embed Spidermonkey inside of a gui program, and allow the user to script how the program reacts to certain events.

Comment: OK, well that makes perfect sense then :-)  Another thing you might want to look into is Node.js source code, as it may be a little less complicated than the guts of a browser.

Comment: Note that the mxr.mozilla.org link you have there is the source for Firefox 3.0 (Gecko 1.9.0).  If you want current source, you want https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/

Comment: i came looking for something else to this question, though it is asked just they way i'd have liked to seen. My question is that events act or are Asynchronous? While javascript is synchronous! So how does it go. I read somewhere that there is a loop going for every event etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SpiderMonkey itself doesn't have anything involving event handling.  Events are purely a DOM thing.

The click event is fired by the browser code (the thing embedding SpiderMonkey), not by SpiderMonkey itself.  See http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e60b8be7a97b/content/events/src/nsEventStateManager.cpp for the code that's responsible for dispatching things like click.

The browser is also what defines setter methods that take an assignment to the `onclick` property and turn it into an event listener registration.  See http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e60b8be7a97b/dom/base/nsDOMClassInfo.cpp#l7624 which is called from `nsEventReceiverSH::SetProperty` and handles properties whose name (`id` in this code) passes the `IsEventName` test.

When event listeners are registered and an event is fired, the event dispatcher manages calls to the listeners; the `nsJSEventListener` link you found is the glue that converts a C++ `HandleEvent` call into a call to a JS function.

So in your case, you want some sort of registration/unregistration mechanism for listeners and then your implementation will fire events and dispatch them to listeners.  How you do this last part is pretty open-ended; the Gecko implementation has a lot of constraints due to needing to implement the DOM Events specification, but you should be able to do something much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

1. HTML uses sink/bubble event propagation schema: http://catcode.com/domcontent/events/capture.html
2. There are "physical" events (mouse, keyboard)  and logical/synthesized ones (focus,click, value_changed, etc.)
3. onClick is a logical event - generated as a result of mouse, touch and/or keyboard events.
4. Mouse (or finger touch) originated click event is a result of mouse down, move and up events. Note that mouse down, move and up are sinking/bubbling events. Target element(s) in these "primordial" events will be the target(or source) of the click event. If mouse-down/up events have different targets (DOM element) then their common parent is used.
5. Sequence of mouse down, move and up events may produce different logical events: click, swipe/scroll, etc.

I believe this is a full list of basic concepts.