# how to loop this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Thanks to some help on here I have a way of previewing images selected for and upload using:

```
<input type='file' name="files[]" onchange="readURL(this);" multiple />
<div id="previews"></div>

<script>
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var container = $('#previews');
                var image = $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result).width(150);
                image.appendTo(container);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I was wondering how to loop this function for each file selected on the input? I just don't see where to use something like .each()

**edit:**

am trying this.. but its wrong somewhere, as it displays 2 previews but both of the same image?

```
function readURL(input) {
    $.each(input.files,function(i) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var container = $('#previews');
            var image = $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result).width(150);
            image.appendTo(container);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    });
}
```

Comment: because the function is called on change event; there are no loops.

Comment: Do you mean loop over the selected images if more than one image is selected, like `input.files[2]` etc.

Comment: you can read more about event in programming, especially in JS here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758363/how-does-event-handling-work-internally-with-javascript

Comment: @Vdt - events are'nt really relevant, you can select more than one image, and when the change event occurs there is a list of images available in the callback etc.

Comment: I see your edit, you need to change the last line of code - input.files[i] instead of input.files[0]

Comment: Also, you don't need to wrap the whole function in a loop, only the last line where the file is selected.

Answer (score 2):

[`input.files`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-files) is a [`FileList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist), which acts like an array.
You can use [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) on it like any other array.

Comment: If you found the definition from w3c is hard to read, here's an [easier-to undertand-one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileList).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over the last line, where the file is selected.

```
function readURL(input) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var container = $('#previews');
        var image = $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result).width(150);
        image.appendTo(container);
    };

    $.each(input.files,function(i) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    });
}
```