# How to show previews of selected files

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, preview

How can i show the previews of selected files?I'm getting single image preview now.how can i loop the function?I've lready checked this [how to loop this function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791766/how-to-loop-this-function.But) that solution didn't worked for me.Plz help me.Thanks in advance...

my code:

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
var container = $('#mypreviewdiv');
var image = $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result).css("width","70px").css("height","70px");
image.appendTo(container)
};
$.each(input.files,function(i) {
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
});
}
}
```

I've this html:

```
<div id="container">

<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);"  id="fileToUpload" multiple /><br/>
<div id="total">
</div> <!-- end #total-->
<div id="mypreviewdiv" style="width:90%; height:250px; background: #FED8E7;"></div>
<button id="upload_btn">Start Uploading</button><br/>
<div class="progressbar" id="pb">
<div>
</div>    
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="status"></div>     
<div id="uplcomp"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

`reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);`

to

`reader.readAsDataURL(i);`