# How are all the events listeners in JavaScript kept active or alive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, addeventlistener, dom-events

I always wondered how an event handler in JavaScript was always listening for subsequent actions to trigger the event again and again even after the JavaScript code you write has been parsed.
I've tried to research online but I've not found any resources that explains how the events listeners are kept active or alive.

I understand how the call stack works but I just want to know how all the event listeners are kept alive or active.

For example `addEventListener` with a `"click"` event will always run the specified callback if the button is clicked. So how is the callback added by the `addEventListener` method always kept alive or active?

Comment: So, you aren't asking about the *events* but the *handlers*, right?

Comment: OBSERVERS design pattern? https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/observer-design-pattern

Comment: The browser is a huge piece of software. All it has to do is remember the association between an event target and a reference to a handler function.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes I'm wondering how the handlers are called every time when the event is triggered

Comment: [This](https://www.bitovi.com/blog/a-crash-course-in-how-dom-events-work) might help you. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758363/how-does-event-handling-work-internally-within-javascript) is similar to you have asked.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour of JavaScript is commonly described as "the event loop". The JavaScript engine runs and runs and runs and keeps looking for new events. It will run until all event handlers were detached. Now if an event gets triggered, it will end up in an event queue. Then somewhen the event loop takes the event out of the queue, and executes it. That will create a callstack, if that unwinded, the loop continues.

Comment: I'm not sure that addresses OP's question. This is *correct* but OP seems to be confused about how the event listeners themselves are stored and executed.

Comment: @vlaz well, as far as I understand he asks "how event listeners are kept alive", and thats basically what the event loop is for. Other languages execute synchronously till the end of the code, so JS might be confusing ...

Comment: My understanding is that OP is interested how does the browser not dispose of the listeners prematurely.

Comment: Exactly! How are the event handlers stored and executed every time

Comment: How they are stored and executed depends on the engine.

Answer (score 2):

JS Engine keeps in memory all the handlers, attached to  specific events, and it becomes a JS engine to know what event have happened and what handler was attached to that event... Hopeful this will help

Comment: So that means the handlers and events are never cleared from memory after execution?

Comment: Yaaah, thats what JS people call event loop